# how to slice a numpy array with variable start and end indices without a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

We can do slice in numpy as below:

```
a = np.random.randn(10)
b = a[1: 3] #slice with  start=1, end=3
```

Now I have a start tuple and end tuple, I can get these slices with a `for` loop:

```
a = np.random.randn(10)
starts = (1, 2)
ends = (3,4)
all_slices = list()
for s, e in zip(starts, ends):
  all_slices.append( a[s:e])
all_slices = np.stack(all_slices, axis=0)  # shape (2,2)
```

I can make sure every slice range is the same: `ends[i] - starts[i] = M`.
Suppose `len(starts)=len(ends)=N`, can I get an array with shape (N, M) without a `for` loop in numpy?

Comment: I've run into this issue in the past and I cannot remember if there is a way to do this. But I will say you should avoid using `slice` as a variable name since it is a Python keyword.

Comment: Make an advanced indexing array.  Since the lengths are all the same, `np.linspace` does this nicely

Answer (score 0):

`linspace` takes array inputs, so can generate an array of indices

```
In [103]: idx=np.linspace(starts,ends,num=2,dtype=int,endpoint=False).T    
In [104]: idx
Out[104]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

I had to tweak the arguments to integer values, and to skip the end point (`linspace` default).  And the transpose - which isn't so obvious in this 2x2 case.

```
In [105]: a[idx]
Out[105]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Perhaps a simpler way to make the indexing array:

```
In [106]: idx = np.array(starts)[:,None]+np.arange(2)
In [107]: idx
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: what I am trying to do here is "slice"  instead of "index" , I change a =np.arange(10) to a = np.random.randn(10) for clarification, sorry if this misleading you.

Comment: You can't use `a[i : j]` with tuples or anything but scalars.  You have to use `advanced indexing` if you don't want to iterate.